# Linear function with domain an open set

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be normed linear spaces. We know that a function $f:V\to W$ is linear if

$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in V$ and

$f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$, for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Is it true that**  if I restrict the same function $f$ to an open set of the domain, say $A\subset V$, then $\left.f\right|_A:A\to W$ is **not** a linear function, as $A$ is not a vector space? Or can I somehow argue that for a sufficiently small neighborhood of the domain, $x+y$ is defined, and hence $\left.f \right|_A$ is still "locally linear"?

Comment: No.  The requirments imply A is empty or A = V or f is zero function.

Comment: @WilliamElliot no as in "it is not linear?"

Comment: Since f is linear,  A is empty or A = V or f is zero function.  Thus a function that is locally linear would be the zero map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear map is a synonymous of linear space homomorphism, that is a map that preserves the linear algebraic structure of the domain. So a linear map must be defined on a linear space.

The fact that a map satisfies the relations that you wrote (additivity and homogeneity) is a map that simply preserves linear combinations when they are defined and you can only say that such a map is (uniquely) prolongable by linearity to the (linear) span of the domain (or that it has a linear prolongation).

Answer (score 0):

No. Because you have that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$, FOR ALL $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, and $x,y\in V$, in particular for all $x,y$ in a not empty subset(open or not) $A$ of $V$.